# Error in compiling in VBA "set-defined type not defined"

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, data-extraction

While compiling the code in VBA I'm facing an error was

> "user-defined type not defined"

Can anyone help me to solve that issue?

```
Sub import_ZipRecruiter()

Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
 IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search? 
search=ax&location=USA&days=5&refine_by_salary=&refine_by_tags=&refine_by_title=&refine_by_org_name="

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

DoEvents
Loop

Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents



Dim idoc As HTMLDocument
Set idoc = IE.Document
Dim r As Long, c As Long

Dim just_job_title As IHTMLElement
Dim dts As IHTMLCollection
Set dts = idoc.getElementsByClassName("just_job_title")
c =1 ; r=1

For Each just_job_title In dts

Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(r, c) = just_job_title.innerText
c = c + 1
Next just_job_title

End Sub
```

Comment: If you press "Debug" when you get the error, which line is highlighted?

Comment: this is the line "Dim idoc As HTMLDocument" 13th line

Comment: You use early binding without a reference to the libraries **Microsoft HTML Object Library** and **Microsoft Internet Controls**. You can read here how to set a reference via *Tools -> References...* and about the differences between early and late binding http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2018/09/vba-referencing-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/ and here deeper information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to get the desired output. This time you should not require any reference to the libraries to execute the script.

```
Sub GetJobTitles()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?%20%20search=ax&location=USA&days=5&refine_by_salary=&refine_by_tags=&refine_by_title=&refine_by_org_name="
    Dim post As Object, R&

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        For Each post In .document.getElementsByTagName("article")
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("just_job_title")(0).innerText
            Cells(R, 2) = post.getElementsByClassName("name")(0).innerText
            Cells(R, 3) = post.getElementsByClassName("location")(0).innerText
        Next post
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How can i extract along with that role,need extract company Name  and Location.please help me that also

Comment: If suppose want extract the data from multiple web pages
Example : URL's link in the below
( 1.https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?days=5&search=nav&location=USA&page=2
2.https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?days=5&search=nav&location=USA&page=3
..and so on) 

into one excel sheet.

Comment: Please ask a new question describing your further requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, for that and i posted a new question,please go through it.

Comment: Here is the new link "https://stackoverflow.com/q/60145311/12837128"