# Url changes dynamically and need to extract the data into same excel sheet.using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Url changes dynamically
For Example

1. https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?days=5&search=nav&location=USA&page=2
2. https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?days=5&search=nav&location=USA&page=3

into same excel sheet

```
 Sub GetJobTitles()
 Const Url$ = "https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?days=5&search=nav&location=USA"
 Dim post As Object, R&

 With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 .Visible = True
 .navigate Url
 While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
 For Each post In .document.getElementsByTagName("article")
 R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("just_job_title")(0).innerText
 Cells(R, 2) = post.getElementsByClassName("name")(0).innerText
 Cells(R, 3) = post.getElementsByClassName("location")(0).innerText

 Next post
 .Quit
 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Does the change in discussion mean the page number (3 instead of 2)? If yes, where do you want to save the following page data? In a different sheet, after the place where the previous one finishes? If anything matches your wish, where do you want the data from the following pages to be returned? Do you have list with URL to be used? Where from the changing URL must be received?

Comment: yes,in the same sheet,It start from where the previous data finishes,pages should be save in the excel sheet,URL will be received from excel sheet only

Comment: Where URLs are kept in that Excel sheet? Do you have a range, a kind of list with all URLs to be processed? If yes, the list in discussion does exist in the same sheet?

Comment: In conclusion, would you like to extract data from all existing pages of that URL, or something else?

Comment: No,thanks The problem was resolved with below code

Comment: But, the below code does exactly that... It increments the page number for each loop cycle and exits it when `elem` does not return anything.

Comment: Yes,exactly that only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work. Give it a shot:

```
Sub GetJobInfo()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.ziprecruiter.com/candidate/search?days=5&search=nav&location=USA&page="
    Dim IE As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim post As Object, elem$, R&, I&: I = 1

    Do
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate URL & I
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            On Error Resume Next
            elem = .document.getElementsByTagName("article")(0).innerText
            On Error GoTo 0

            If elem = "" Then Exit Do

            For Each post In .document.getElementsByTagName("article")
                R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("just_job_title")(0).innerText
                Cells(R, 2) = post.getElementsByClassName("name")(0).innerText
                Cells(R, 3) = post.getElementsByClassName("location")(0).innerText
            Next post
        End With
        I = I + 1
        elem = ""
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Loop
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey SIM i posted a new question/error,find that question URL in below.Thanks in advance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163474