# while compiling the following code i have an error Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

```
 Sub GetJobDetails()
 Const URL$ = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=103644278&keywords=nav&location=United%20States&start="
 Dim IE As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 Dim post As Object, elem$, R&, I&: I = 0
 Do
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL & I
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        On Error Resume Next
        elem = .document.getElementsByTagName("li")(0).innerText
        On Error GoTo 0

        If elem = "" Then Exit Do

        For Each post In .document.getElementsByTagName("li")
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = post.getElementsByClassName("js_focusable")(0).innerText          
Cells(R, 2) = post.getElementsByClassName("job-card-search__company-name-link")(0).innerText                   
    Cells(R, 3) = post.getElementsByClassName("job-card-search__location")(0).innerText
    Next post
    End With
    I = I + 25
    elem = ""
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Loop
    IE.Quit
 End Sub
```

what exactly

> "Object variable or with block variable not set"

means,may be the url was wrong,The url will changes dynamically like in last 
 "start =25/50/75"

Comment: 16th line it was showing that error

Comment: Before trying to access the `innerText` of an object, make sure the object is not null. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955755/extracting-the-inner-text-from-span-using-vba/44956013#44956013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the content from next pages you need to log in to that site first. The good news is you can parse the content from it's landing page using xhr which is way faster than IE.

Working script (content from first page only):

```
Sub GetJobDetails()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=103644278&keywords=nav&location=United%20States&start=0&redirect=false&position=1&pageNum=0"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim I&, R&

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        With Html.querySelectorAll("li.job-result-card")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .Item(I).outerHTML
                R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = Htmldoc.querySelector(".screen-reader-text").innerText
                On Error Resume Next
                Cells(R, 2) = Htmldoc.querySelector("h4.result-card__subtitle > a").innerText
                On Error GoTo 0
                Cells(R, 3) = Htmldoc.querySelector("span.job-result-card__location").innerText
            Next I
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Before executing the above script make sure to add the following reference:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Once again, you need to log in to that site to parse the content from next pages.

Comment: Example

URL 1."https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?  f_TPR=r604800&geoId=103644278&keywords=nav&location=United%20States"
         2."https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/? 
 f_TPR=r604800&geoId=103644278&keywords=nav&location=United%20States&start=25"
         3."https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_TPR=r604800&geoId=103644278&keywords=nav&location=United%20States&start=50"..


like the URL changes dynamically in the above is shown,how find the solution for that.Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes,you said can extract from only one page,but its hard\can't identify from which page we got that data.